# "One of my most dearest, and closest friends"?

Tags: descriptive-grammar

When wanting to note a very close friendship, is this appropriate?

> One of my most dearest, and closest friends

Or should it be

> One of my dearest and most closest friends

Can 'most' simply not be used?

Comment: "Makes sense" is a fairly broad brush. The whole "Buffalo buffalo.." thing *makes sense*, once someone explains it to you. But: **no** don't say "*most closest*"; *closest* is perfect just by itself.

Comment: "most" has _the same meaning_ as the "-est" suffix, so "dearest" actually means "most dear".

Comment: In other words, no, "most ...est"  is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

***"One of my dearest and closest friends"*** needs neither "most" nor the comma before the and in your title.

Any way you render it, with zero, one, or two 'most's will be perfectly understandable, but as explained in comments, the suffix "-est" *means the same thing* as "most," so "most dearest" is the same as saying "most most dear."

It's a common mistake, so please don't feel stupid for asking!

Answer (score 1):

Your example falls under the category of *Superlatives*.

But your phrase, corrected, would be: "one of my dearest and closest friends". (This might sound odd to some. We usually say, "one of my close friends" and when it comes to "the closest", there's only one! That explains why it's called a *superlative*.)

The following are the general rules to form the *Superlatives*:

(1)  **the** + adjective + 'est' (if the adj ends with a 'y', 'i' replaces it and any other changes as required)

(2)  **the** + most + adjective

(3)  **the** + irregular forms

Most short adjectives follow (1) in the formation of superlatives: dearest, craziest, cleverest, longest, etc.

For longer adjectives, 'most' introduces the superlative element (2). For e.g., most beautiful, most boring, most common, most intelligent, etc.

Irregular forms (3): good/best, bad/worst, many/most, etc.

(I believe these are the only three categories)

Comment: +1. It's worth noting, however, that the superlatives of some short adjectives, such as "fun," require the "most" construction rather than the "-est" construction: "more fun" rather than "funnest."

Comment: @Nicole. It's true that its construction as an adjective 'funnest' (wonder why the comment section doesn't recognize it) exists. 

I guess, you're referring to 'fun' as a noun, in which case, what you say is correct (most fun).

Comment: For the adjective "fun," "more fun" and "most fun" are more common (and more likely to be considered correct) than "funner" and "funnest." Webster notes that "funner" and "funnest" are _sometimes_ used, and Dictionary.com notes them as informal. Of course, some dictionaries don't acknowledge "fun" as an adjective at all.

Comment: Thanks Nicole. I'm just wondering if you can think of some examples of 'fun' (adj) in the comparative/superlative forms. I'm sure, "My most fun boyfriend" would sound odd to many ears.

Comment: I don't know why, but I've found that "fun" as an adjective (as well as its comparative and superlative) is more likely to be in the predicate: "My current boyfriend is more fun than my ex" sounds much more natural than "My more fun boyfriend." I'm sure there's some rule that governs this (like how you can say "The baby is asleep" but not "the asleep baby"), but I'm not sure what it is.